# Separate ASCII Serial Data Into Individual Matrix

Tags: matlab, serial-port, ascii, scanf

First time poster here. I am using an accelorometer to measure three axis x, y & z. I am streaming the three variables through a pic microcontroller and sending via UART in ASCII format into my laptop. Using fscanf command I recieve a string of comma separated data in the form x=0000,y=0508,z=0000,x=0000,y=0503,z=0000, etc... I want to separate the information and place into three matrix of the form 
x = `[005, 010, 000....]`; y = `[503, 000, 450....]`; z = `[000, 000, 500.....]`;
for further analysis, plotting etc..
Here is my code so far:

```
clear all;
close all;

s = serial('COM4'); %assigns the object s to serial port

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 256); %number of bytes in inout buffer
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'hardware');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
set(s, 'Timeout',10);

disp(get(s,'Name'));
prop(1)=(get(s,'BaudRate'));
prop(2)=(get(s,'DataBits'));
prop(3)=(get(s, 'StopBit'));
prop(4)=(get(s, 'InputBufferSize'));

fopen(s); %opens the serial port
fscanf(s)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp`:

```
>> str = 'x=0000,y=0508,z=0000,x=0000,y=0503,z=0000';
>> pat = '([xyz])=([0-9\.]*),?';
>> toks = regexp(str, pat, 'tokens')
toks = 

Columns 1 through 5

{1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}

Column 6

{1x2 cell}

>> toks{1}

ans = 

'x'    '0000'
```

The question mark at the end of `pat` makes it insensitive to the case where you don't have a trailing `','`, and if you don't want to extract the variable names as well (i.e., in your case you probably don't need this info because you know they always come in the same sequence), then just remove the `()` around `[xyz]`.

To extract the values in double form, you can do something like:

```
newXYZ = zeros(length(toks) / 3, 1); 
newFilledLocs = zeros(size(newXYZ)); 
curRow = 1;
for nTok = 1:length(toks)
    col = [];
    switch toks{nTok}{1}
        case 'x', col = 1; 
        case 'y', col = 2; 
        case 'z', col = 3; 
        otherwise, error('Invalid variable name ''%s''', toks{nTok{1}});
    end; 
    newXYZ(curRow, col) = str2double(toks{nTok}{2});
    if all(newFilledLocs(curRow, :))
        curRow = curRow + 1; 
    end
end
```